# Scraping ads url from the website using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

Topic : website scraping using bs4

Question : I need to extract ads url from the website.
I extracted all the links from the website but, I can't find any ads link from that website which contains ads

My code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.premiumswat.me').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source , 'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all('a' , href = True):
    print(link['href'])
```

Comment: This could be because the links are added using JavaScript you can use [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) and then scrap data, The following question might be helpful [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Comment: Can you add the website link as well?

Comment: Ok, now I added the website link

Comment: I did not find any add link that website

Comment: How can you tell which link contains ads and which doesn't?

Comment: Which add links do you mean? Do you have an example? GoogleAds?

Comment: The above site link contains,  adstera ads.. .